#  Change in Twitter API?  tweet user list stopped working

Tags: jquery, twitter

I have the following code I was using to display a list of tweets from select users. Today it stopped showing tweets for the user list here, and is showing tweets from any user's tweet that include the query I set in the parameters. Has there been an update to Twitter API that I am not aware of?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".tweet").tweet({
        username: ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'],
        page: 1,
        avatar_size: 32,
        count: 9000,
        query: "@mysearchterm OR #mysearchterm",
        loading_text: "loading ..."
    }).bind("loaded", function () {
        var ul = $(this).find(".tweet_list");
        var ticker = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                ul.find('li:first').fadeIn("fast").animate({
                    marginTop: '70px'
                }, 500, function () {
                    $(this).detach().hide().appendTo(ul).fadeIn("fast").removeAttr('style');
                });
                ticker();
            }, 5500);
        };
        ticker();
    });
});
});
```

Comment: I am trying to restrict it to the user: parameter this is what is not working. the user parameter. It is ignoring the user list of accounts and pulling from any account that matches the query

Comment: Not sure if this will impact you **on top** of your current issue but the 05-Sep-2012 update included many other changes: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither credible nor official, but since you have no answers at all...
I assume that you are using the plugin jquery.tweet.js from seaofclouds ([tweet.seaofclouds.com/](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) or https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet).
Since a very old commit (Feb 06, 2010), the username option is ignored if you set the query option (see the function build_api_url in [jquery.tweet.js](https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet/blob/master/tweet/jquery.tweet.js#L145)). To do what you want you need to append the users to the query string, something like

```
query: "@mysearchterm OR #mysearchterm OR from:user1 OR from:user2 OR from:user3"
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aalmeida/pDz5P/2/).